# How to move/copy any type of file from asset file to scoped storage ANDROID Q in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

I have already succeeded with this operation with images, but I cannot do it with other type of file, in my case I try to insert a database.

Here is an example of the code for the images:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        try {
            try {
                pictures = assetManager.list("photos/dataset1");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
            }
            if (pictures != null) {
                for (String filename : pictures) {
                    InputStream in;
                    OutputStream out;
                    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("photos/dataset1/"+filename);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    saveImageToGallery(bitmap);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This method below works for the images :

```
public void saveImageToGallery(Bitmap bitmap) {
    OutputStream outputStream;
    Context myContext = requireContext();
    try {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            ContentResolver contentResolver = requireContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"Image_"+".jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, outputStream);
            Objects.requireNonNull(outputStream);

        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and there my try for the other type of file :

```
        AssetManager assetManager = Objects.requireNonNull(requireContext()).getAssets();
    Context myContext = requireContext();
    //Essential for creating the external storage directory for the first launch
    myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File databasesFolder = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent(), "com.mydb.orca/databases");
    databasesFolder.mkdirs();

 if (files!= null) {
        for (String filename : files) {
            InputStream in;
            OutputStream out;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("database/test/" + filename);
                File outFile = new File(databasesFolder, filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Error NPE", "files is null");
    }



    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

This code above is not working, I mean, I don't get any errors or the desired result. I want something like this or a function similary as the function for my images but for any type of file.
When I run my application I have no error however nothing happens

Comment: `have already succeeded with this operation` ? Which operation?

Comment: For images, I wrote it at the beginning and then I have given the code for the images ? Should I modify my post to be clearer ?

Comment: Yes. We cannot read in your post what kind of operation you wanna do. Dont refer to a title please.

Comment: "This function above is not working" -- please explain in detail what you mean by this. For example, are you crashing? If so, use Logcat to examine the stack trace. Also, you need to tell us how you are getting the value of `databasesFolder`.

Comment: Unless you are the developer of `com.mydb.orca`, you have no read or write access to that location on Android 11+. Have you tried copying your database to a more conventional location?

Comment: This location was created in my application package before android 11, it looked something like this : "Android/data/com.data.myApp/com.myd.orca/databases/myfiles"

Comment: add this and try again :  `contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution, I pretty sure it's not the best way but it work.
I give me access to all files acccess by this way :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
  try {
        Intent intentFiles = new Intent();
        intentFiles.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        Uri uriFiles = Uri.fromParts("package", myContext.getPackageName(), null);
        intentFiles.setData(uriFiles);
        myContext.startActivity(intentFiles);
       } catch (Exception e)
       {
        Intent intentFiles = new Intent();
        intentFiles.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        myContext.startActivity(intentFiles);
       }
```

add this line to your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

after that, this code below work :

```
AssetManager assetManager = Objects.requireNonNull(requireContext()).getAssets();
Context myContext = requireContext();
//Essential for creating the external storage directory for the first launch
myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
File databasesFolder = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent(), "com.mydb.orca/databases");
databasesFolder.mkdirs();

 if (files!= null) {
    for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in;
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("database/test/" + filename);
            File outFile = new File(databasesFolder, filename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }
    }
} else {
    Log.e("Error NPE", "files is null");
}



private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

}

if someone have a best solution it should be nice

I tested on android 11 and it work